# trying to place a table below some text, issue with css

Tags: html, css, transform

I have some html with some text and a table, however the table is going over the text. I can use  margin-top: 1100px; on the tablecontainer but this is inconstant between browsers and screen sizes. I have tried changing the position to absolute or fixed etc but sure there is a simple solution?
note the issue appears to be with transform

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.tablecontainer {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 45px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #55608f;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

tbody td {
  position: relative;
}

tbody td:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}

.center {
  border: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
  color: #41cb97;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  title
</div>

<div class="center">
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>

  <div class="tablecontainer">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th align="left" width="30%">Product</th>
          <th align="left" width="30%">class 1</th>
          <th width="5%">Price</th>
          <th align="left" width="30%">class 2</th>
          <th width="5%">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td>0.55</td>
            <td align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <img src="images/prices.png">
```

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: ignore the .container class - thats not used - used in tbody td:hover:before  to get the hover effect to work

Comment: Get rid of `position: relative;` and that should fix your issues

Comment: hmm that puts the table in the top left of the page

Comment: the issue is with transform - which is needed for the vertical mouse over effect. I can just remove this and it positions ok, but it would be nice to keep the effect

Comment: by "below" do you mean "after" or "behind"? Is the text to be at the top and the table at the bottom for example?   Usually when there is a CSS issue it it because there is TOO MUCH CSS and adding more to "fix" is not the best way to address it.

Comment: after - at the moment the text or some of it is behind the table

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML semantics, in other words, instead of `<div id=title>`, use `<h1>`. Adjust default layout (inline vs block) as little as possible to achieve what you are after. This means using `position: absolute` or `relative` as little as possible, rarely.

```html
<h1 id="title">
  title
</h1>

<div class="center">
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
  <p>
    blar blar blar
  </p>
    <table>
      <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th align="left" width="30%">Product</th>
          <th align="left" width="30%">class 1</th>
          <th width="5%">Price</th>
          <th align="left" width="30%">class 2</th>
          <th width="5%">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
            <td align="left"> blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td>0.55</td>
            <td align="left">blar blar blar</td>
            <td>1.5</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```